# Compare the domains of two email in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, compare

## The situation:

I have one table: Jobs postings table (which contains information about the jobs posted by an employer).
The job postings table  contains two emails contact: employer_email and job_email. The two emails can be similar or different.

```
*Jobs postings table*
>job_id  
>email_job
>email_employer  
>employer_id
```

## What I am looking for:

is to compare the domains of two emails and if they are different return the value 1 or 0 otherwise. 
For example if email_employer is maman@maman.org and the job email is maman@gmail.com I would like to have an indicator that will return 1 because the domains (@maman.org & @gmail.com) are different.

## What I have tried so far:

```
select email_job, email_employer



    case    

    when email_job like '%'+ email_employer +'%'  then 0    

    else 1        

    end compare_domain   

    from job_postings
```

I have been trying for a week now, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @EMAIL_JOB VARCHAR(255) = 'test1@email_job.com'
DECLARE @EMAIL_EMPLOYER VARCHAR(255) = 'test2@email_employer.com'
SELECT CASE
         WHEN SUBSTRING(@EMAIL_JOB, CHARINDEX('@', @EMAIL_JOB, 1) + 1, LEN(@EMAIL_JOB))
              = SUBSTRING(@EMAIL_EMPLOYER, CHARINDEX('@', @EMAIL_EMPLOYER, 1) + 1, LEN(@EMAIL_EMPLOYER))
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
       END
```

Comment: Thanks Danny, I have a little trouble to understand how your query works!  In my query I create a 'compare_domain' indicator. Do I have a new indicator in your suggestion ?  Do I need to precise the table like " from job_postings" ?